# exposing sql server primary key through WCF

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008, windows-phone-7

I am exposing Sql Server data through WCF to be consumed on a WP7 application. Right now I have a choice, either I work with the data using the primary key or other columns for the same table.

I personally think it is best not to expose the PK, not that the phone is not secure, but because of the internet. But, please advice me.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the PK you mentioned is of type int and it would not be secure to expose the values.

In this case I'd add an alternate key of type GUID (uniqueidentifier in SQL Server). The field can be populated using the `System.Guid.NewGuid()` method from .Net code, or using the `newid()` function in SQL.

That would make the key not predictable. For example, if a person sniffs your WCF traffic and sees a PK with a value of 4, they can try close values (2,3,5...) to access other records. GUIDs are not sequential, so it's really hard to guess other key values.

---

Please note that GUIDs take up 4x more storage space than an int (or 2x bigint), so if this will be a large table, the GUID approach could take considerably more space.

In this case, you might reconsider if exposing keys is really a security problem; if the app is designed to be secure, or if all the records are meant to be viewed by anyone then exposing the PK value should not be so bad.

After all, if you look at the URL of this page you will notice the value `8690786`, which most probably is an exposed integer identifier of the question.

Comment: Can you point me to an web page that shows how to implement the GUID in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Here's the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx (_GUIDs_ are called _uniqueidentifier_ in SQL Server). Declare a column of type _uniqueidentifier_ and make sure you populate it by one of the two means I presented in the answer.

Comment: thanks. Small question, in C# will the variable of type string will fit for it?

Comment: you can use `System.Guid` in C#. It's perfectly compatible with uniqueidentifier and it ensures you won't run into any conversion problems.

Comment: I think you could also use `System.String`, but you'll have to make sure the string values you send to DB are valid GUIDs.